# Mutual SSL using: Mono,C#, and Self-Signed Certificates

Tags: c#, ssl, mono

Here is the project: 
I'm creating a TcpListener in C#, that will host on a Linux box using Mono.

Then I will have a TcpClient (also Mono on Linux) that will connect to it, and because I can't have a username/password auth, I would like it that clients connect with a "client certificate", that I will generate with my Root CA (also self-generated)

I can't only have the client connect securely to the server, I need my TcpListener to trust my client connection too.

What i have done so far:
I have exported my server certificate as PFX:

And loaded this into the code:

```
sslCertificate = new X509Certificate2("myCert.pfx", "password");
```

Now, if I run the code as below:

```
bool requireClientCertificate = false; // <== turn on/off
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(netStream, false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptRemoteCertificate));
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(sslCertificate, requireClientCertificate, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
```

With `requireClientCertificate = false`, then I can use a browser to view this page perfectly fine. Of course, I would have already imported my Root CA, in order to see this page, otherwise Chrome gives me a certificate warning.

Right, so there is no problem with this so far... and SSL is established, but technically anyone could connect to this TcpListner.

Now I set `requireClientCertificate = true`, and this is where things fall apart.

I realize I need to generate a client certificate, so I did that, exported that, and imported it into my PC. I can see it under the certificate list in Chrome, and I am prompted to use it when I first attempt to connect the TcpListner.

However, doing all that, still does not solve things.

I have also installed the Root CA onto the server using:

1. copy to /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/MyRootCA.crt
2. editing /etc/ca-certificates.conf
3. update-ca-certificates
   (This showed 1 new certificate installed.. but still did'nt help)

Then I tried:
`certmgr -add -c -v -m Trust /home/Certs/MyRootCA.crt`
Still not working, so i tried:
`certmgr -add -c -v -m CA /home/Certs/MyRootCA.crt`

So from what I can see the RootCA is installed.

If I try connect with Chrome I'm getting:
`RemoteCertificateChainErrors` in the `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback`

And if I loop thought the chain, I get : `PartialChain` in the Status Information.

And if I test with OpenSSL, I get:
`RemoteCertificateChainErrors` with: `UntrustedRoot` in the Status Information

The totally confusing part on this, is that, my RemoteCertificate of the TcpListner is not null - it is in fact a the certificate that I installed on the browser, and can see the RootCA that singed it too (Issuer).

If I actually do a: `wget https://api.myserver.com --certificate=/my.crt --private-key=/my.key --ca-certificate=/MyRootCA.crt`, it connects and downloaded my expedited results.

So, questions:

1. Is this connection actually mutually secure?
2. What are those errors about? *UntrustedRoot* and *PartialChain*
3. If it has these errors, but still can present a RemoteCertificate, does that mean its a mutually secure connection or not?

In the past I have done this on Windows Server with a commercial CA certificates (DigiCert E.V.), and other (out of my control) CPE's, and they worked without errors. This is the only difference I have noticed. Is this the reason? Does Linux / Mono, have some sort of additional knowledge about certificates, that if you generate your own Root CA... it can't trust it completely?

**EDIT:**

I have not got a full answer, but I have discovered a few things. Would really appreciate some assistance from someone who has this working.

So what I discovered that you can check the stream (ssl) properties of `.IsMutuallyAuthenticated` and `.IsSigned` and `.IsEncrypted`. This is vital to this, and especially `.IsMutuallyAuthenticated`.

As it turned out, by manipulating the `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` response true/false, you can handle the errors that you "don't mind", and reject the others. In that case the connection disconnects and an error is raised. However, in my *RemoteCertificateChainErrors* I was able to return true... and when doing that `stream.IsMutuallyAuthenticated`, was returning True! Yay

Ok, now I build the client with :

```
HttpWebRequest requestObj = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
requestObj.ClientCertificates = certs;
```

This presents the certificates to my server code, and now this is where its interesting... After getting the response object:

```
HttpWebResponse responseObj = (HttpWebResponse)requestObj.GetResponse();
Debug.WriteLine("IsMutuallyAuthenticated: " + responseObj.IsMutuallyAuthenticated);
```

Even though I'm getting my expected results back, and `responseObj.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK`, `IsMutuallyAuthenticated` is false. So clearly this is an issue with the certificate that i'm presenting client side.

It seems that the client side code can NOT trust the certificate it is presenting, but I have installed the Root CA locally on the PC. Both Local Machine, and User. If I open the store - and list the certs, its there.

This seems like its more difficult than it should be. Any assistance would help.

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-5.20.1.19/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/HttpWebResponse.cs Sounds like source code is your only resource. BTW, today you should use .NET Core in most cases to replace Mono.

Comment: Thanks @Lex Li, the project will convert quite easily to .net Core, except my CPE is ARM based - I understand that this is not officially supported, and ill probably run into more issues that way. 
In the mean while I eventual found that `X509Certificate2.Verify()` was failing on windows, but succeeding on Linux. Either way the server code failed the Remote Certificate. For now i'm overriding the errors, as I have tried "faking" it with other certificates, and they all fail. Clearly this is a remarkably unpopular form of securing an API with a CPE - I wouldn't have thought so.

Comment: .NET Core started to support ARM32 in 2.1, and ARM64 should be supported officially once 3.0 is released.

Comment: Yes, I saw that now. The option to go to .net core is tempting. I have done a hello world test, but in my Conversion Analysis, about half of the projects (around 10), could not convert (around 80%). Some things need to be handled quite differently. At the same time my Mono results are 100% (or course). In truth - this project will never ever be run on windows (it can't), so where i'm thinking is "if i have to re-write and learn a new system, then should I not write in something like C++ that can compile native to Linux"?

Comment: 100% on Mono can be an illusion, as Microsoft's current effort on Mono is on Xamarin/Unity, not desktop or web. Conversion from .NET Framework to .NET Core might be a smaller percentage on chart, but once you start migration, the effort is controllable, and can be accelerated when the team know more about .NET Core. If you prefer to rewrite in C++, then good luck.